# The difference between maxIterations and run in MLlib KMeans?

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

As i understand the `run` parameter is the number of times KMeans is repeated to get the optimal clusters and `maxIterations` is the number of iteration in each `run` , is it correct? what are the best values for them in case of a 5000 datapoints?

Answer (score 1):

Edited my answer as I miss-read your question.

> As i understand run is the number of times KMeans is repeated to get the optimal clusters and maxIterations means the number of iteration in each run , is it correct

Yes, that is correct. Normally you only run k-means once. The maximum iterations is the maximum number of iterations you will allow for the k-means centroid update loop to occur.

Spark's implementation does supports what have described with *runs*, ie. how many times do you want to *run* the algorithm. Its usually not necessary. Especially since optimizing the k-means metric does not necessarily optimize what your actual goal is.

> what are the best values for them in case of a 5000 datapoints?

You should not ask such kinds of questions, these things are always problem and data dependent. You should work to better understand the tools you are using and what they mean and how to iterate with them. This will help you avoid putting yourself in such a situation that you want to ask that kind of question, or if it is warranted - what other context is needed (just the number of datums is certainly not enough context for any meaningful discussion).